# Kafka to S3 - How to loading slices from kafka to S3

Tags: java, scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark, apache-kafka

It's not clear to me if there is some kind of plugin to consume data from kafka topics and insert them to the S3.

I already found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255714/kafka-storm-hdfs-s3-data-flow), but I could not solve this issue yet, there is this [project](https://github.com/razvan/kafka-s3-consumer), but honestly is hard to use because the last commit is from 2 years ago.

The main goal to me it was consume directly from kafka to spark jobs, but I think this can be a kind of complicated, so if could populate S3 with slices of events from kafka is enough to me.

Also, there is any consumer example in scala? It is kind of funny because kafka is built in scala but the documentation code is java. =p

I appreciate any help

**Updated**:

[Camus](https://github.com/linkedin/camus) may be a option too

Comment: camus is for taking data from kafka and distributing it to hdfs, so it is definitely a viable solution to your problem, also for the consumers you can use the java api in scala so that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This tool from pinterest was the perfect answer for me.

[Secor](https://github.com/pinterest/secor)

Comment: Secor is great reliable tool, not much documentation and examples though. However once you figure out how to use it, does the job well.

Answer (score 0):

StreamX (https://github.com/qubole/streamx) which is based on Kafka-Connect framework can help copy data from Kafka to S3 reliably. It's feature-rich, supports multiple output formats and different partitioning mechanisms.